# VLC is unable to play rtsp Streaming coming through a GST-RTSP server, while gstreamer and GOM player are playing very well

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, libvlc

I am stuck in a strange problem. I have created a media player in qt using libvlc now i am playing a rtsp streaming in it. It is unable to play it. It's log file is as mentioned below. Is there any mechanism that i have to implement or is there any buffer related problem with vlc. I have tried original VLC media player to play the incoming stream, but it is also giving the same output. While this stream is working properly on GOM player. 
Another rtsp streamings are working fine except this one.
This streaming is coming from a Raspberry Pi board Camera. Which is streaming using GST-RTSP server of Gstreamer. And the receiving platform is Windows.

**End Log details of VLC**

```
C:\Users\shubham_0_nas\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
main debug: no meta reader modules matched
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.15:8554/test' successfully opened
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
live555 debug: tk->rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
main error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
```

Buffering 0% is not stopped any time.
Any kind of help is appreciated. If someone has experienced this before then please guide me through the problems i am facing. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all try play same link with different Vlc versions (2.1.5, 2.2.0, 3.0 nightly) - maybe it's regression or was already fixed.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your Quick reply RSA. I have checked in some of the different builds already and now i'll check them again. The main problem is that it's only creating a problem when playing this stream. Not others. I am using vlc2.1.5

Comment: Did you use maximum verbosity level for log (-vvv)?

Comment: After doing verbose=3 There is only new thing in log files is main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround
main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround
main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround
main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 485x320 window
main debug: Buffering 0%
main error: pictures leaked, trying to workaround

Comment: All the builds are behaving same they are loading a single image (the initial one) and then showing buffering 0%. I think there must be some problem related to buffer. Can i set the buffer size to 0 so that i can see only the frames which i am receiving?

Comment: Sorry, then I can't answer this question without Vlc sources debugging...

Comment: Ok. Then i'll be checking for the relevant solution. I'll post it soon if i found one. By the way thanks for looking into..

Comment: While running the vlc in a separate system, I've got some different error "Invalid mix of IDR and non IDR slices". I don't know how to resolve it. It seems that it's the error cause of some problem while streaming from the server end, Not with the VLC

Comment: Don't see any way to solve this problem without debugging...

Comment: Ok, Now i am checking at the server end from where streaming is being done. Most probably the chances of error are there because vlc is playing all other RTSP streaming except this one.